# NullReference Exception when changing the color of rows in DGV on form load

Tags: c#, datagridview

On form load event when I load data in datagridview after that I call this function to change color of those rows in which the paid expense is Yes but it gives me nullreference exception on the line

PaidStatus = ExpensesDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();

```
public void ExpenseRowColor()
    {
        int i;
        string PaidStatus;

        for (i = 1; i <= ExpensesDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            PaidStatus = ExpensesDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();

            if (PaidStatus == "Yes")
            {
                ExpensesDataGridView.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which part of your statement is coming back as null?

Comment: PaidStatus = ExpensesDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();

Comment: Yes but which part of that statement? `Cells` or `Value`? It's gotta be one of those if it's getting to that line. Debug and figure out which of those is null.

Comment: `i < ExpensesDataGridView.Rows.Count`

Answer (score 0):

Cells start from a 0th index, meaning that the 4th cell would be at `[3]` index . In the same way, the row and column indices start from 0 as well but your loop starts from an `int i = 1` so I suggest you change that as well to: `for (i = 0; i < ExpensesDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++){}`

Or use `foreach` :

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ExpensesDataGridView)
 { 
     //use row here
 }
```

Comment: There are 5 cloumns in DGV so the index for the cell stays 4

Comment: Fix the loop as i told you to

Comment: tried it but still problem exist

Comment: use foreach (DataGridViewRow row in  ExpensesDataGridView)
{
    //use row here
}